# JQuery returning name of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so I've been working on this system that should return the value of the name attribute inside the  tag but no matter what button I click I still get the name of the first one...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".vehicles-sub").click(function() {
    $('.popup_content').show();
    $('.black_overlay').show();
    var name = $("button").attr("name");
    alert(name);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vehicles_case_form">
  <div class='vehicle_top_form'>
    <h1>Vehicle Four</h1>
    <hr/>
  </div>

  <div class='vehicles_bottom_form'>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever...</p>
  </div>

  <div class='vehicles_button_form'>
    <button class="vehicles-sub" type="submit" name="submit_vehicles_first"> <!-- first name -->
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;PURCHASE
    </button>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="vehicles_case_form">
  <div class='vehicle_top_form'>
    <h1>Vehicle Five</h1>
    <hr/>
  </div>

  <div class='vehicles_bottom_form'>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever...</p>
  </div>

  <div class='vehicles_button_form'>
    <button class="vehicles-sub" type="submit" name="submit_vehicles_second"> <!-- second name -->
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;PURCHASE
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is, whenever I click the button it will always alert `submit_vehicles_first`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead to refer to the current clicked button :

```
var name = $(this).attr("name");
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".vehicles-sub").click(function() {
    $('.popup_content').show();
    $('.black_overlay').show();
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    alert(name);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vehicles_case_form">
  <div class='vehicle_top_form'>
    <h1>Vehicle Four</h1>
    <hr/>
  </div>

  <div class='vehicles_bottom_form'>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever...</p>
  </div>

  <div class='vehicles_button_form'>
    <button class="vehicles-sub" type="submit" name="submit_vehicles_first"> <!-- first name -->
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;PURCHASE
    </button>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="vehicles_case_form">
  <div class='vehicle_top_form'>
    <h1>Vehicle Five</h1>
    <hr/>
  </div>

  <div class='vehicles_bottom_form'>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever...</p>
  </div>

  <div class='vehicles_button_form'>
    <button class="vehicles-sub" type="submit" name="submit_vehicles_second"> <!-- second name -->
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;PURCHASE
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Same thing happens, I tried with $(this) earlier, but still exactly the same


EDIT: For some reason, I got new Jquery version and it started working.. Thanks mate!